# How to dynamically give color to Text

Tags: android, colors, textview

How to give color to text to dynamically created Textview ?

> TextView b3 = new TextView(this);
>             b3.setLayoutParams(new
>   LayoutParams(
>                       LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
>                       LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
>
> b3.setTextSize(t);
>
> ```
>       b3.setBackgroundColor(#000);
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one works

```
TextView b3 = new TextView(this); b3.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams( LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

b3.setTextSize(t);

      b3.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
```

You cant give # codes directly in the code.

Answer (score 3):

you can do one thing define your color inside the color.xml file as:

```
<color name="demo_color">#E01B4C</color>
```

And then access it as below:

```
b3.setTextColor(R.color.demo_color);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this method :

```
b3.setTextColor(Color.BLUE);
```

Answer (score 1):

`b3.setBackgroundColor(#000);` => `b3.setBackgroundColor(0);` or even `b3.setBackgroundColor(0x000);`